# Crop and boomerang at the same time using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to create a cropped "boomerang" video. Where it would take in a video, take a small segment, crop it and then play that little piece forward and then play it backwards.

`ffmpeg -y -i x.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex 'trim=start=1.32:duration=0.4,crop=500:500:1200:300,split=2[f][ri];[ri]reverse[r];[f][r]concat'  x1.mp4`

The end result, however, is `00:00:02.34` long, almost the exact same as the original `00:00:02.46`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset timestamps after the trim, and disable audio.

`ffmpeg -y -i x.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter_complex 'trim=start=1.32:duration=0.4,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=500:500:1200:300,split=2[f][ri];[ri]reverse[r];[f][r]concat' -an x1.mp4`